# Get inbound email info in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webhooks, contextio

let's say I have an email account and every time I get a new email I want to receive this information in my `c#` code and save some info of that email in `json` format, I have read about `Context.IO`, `Webhooks`, but I have not find any information yet about doing it with `C#` code, could you please give an advice of how can I reach that in my `c#` code? I have an `ASP.net MVC` app, I just want to get some data about a new email every time is received, I have never worked before with `Context.IO` or `webhooks`. How can I do this in C#?

**UPDATE**:

`[HttpPost]
        [System.Web.Mvc.ValidateInput(false)]
        public IHttpActionResult GetEmail(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection form)
        {
            Person person = new Person {
                Name= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Unvalidated.Form["Account_id"],

                LastName= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Unvalidated.Form["webhook_id"]
            };
            db.People.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }`

Comment: It might not be a solution to your problem, but services like mailgun.io can help you in that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Context.IO pretty much does what you're looking for with webhooks. Essentially, you would setup a webhook filter on a user (https://context.io/docs/lite/users/webhooks) and provide which filters to watch out for, if any. Set up an endpoint on your app to receive the webhooks, and when a new message is received by the user, you should receive a webhook postback on that endpoint.

If you just want to test out the webhooks without setting up an endpoint on your end, I would recommend a tool like Mockbin, which allows you to set up mock endpoints and receive data http://mockbin.org/

The payload is in json, so it should be easy to parse on your end. The only thing is that Context.IO does not have a C# library, but you could use a library of your choice (or something like restsharp) to develop straight against the REST API.

Comment: I'm trying to save info about the mails but every time that I try to save it into the database the fields are in blank, maybe I'm not setting well the webhook? But my action controller always is recognized when a new email arrives... this is my code:

Comment: See edited question to see the code in a better format :)